# Use Haskell's Control.Monad.Random.Class.fromList with System.Random

Tags: haskell, random

I want to use `Control.Monad.Random.Class.fromList`

```hs
fromList :: MonadRandom m => [(a, Rational)] -> m a
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#v:fromList

together with `System.Random.mkStdGen`

```hs
mkStdGen :: Int -> StdGen
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:mkStdGen

I see the instance

```hs
(Monad m, RandomGen g) => MonadInterleave (RandT g m)
```

but am not sure how to combine.

Comment: `runRandT (fromList _) (mkStdGen _)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a monad that has an instance of `MonadRandom`, such as `RandT`:

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let stdGen = mkStdGen 2021
  putStrLn $ fst $
    runRand (fromList [("hello", 0.5), ("world", 0.1)]) stdGen
```

Which will yield:

```
world
```